# Age Verification Pop up For Magento Landing Page

Tags: javascript, magento, popup

I need a age verification on loading of Magento Homepage, I have the Javascript code for that, But in which page i have to give  these codes, Any magento experts please reply.

I am Very new to PHP and Magento.

Example :http://www.smirnoff.com/en-us/newmain/home.aspx#axzz2q6ksBK1y

Answer (score 0):

Are Guests allowed on this Shop/Catalog or is it Members only?

Members only: 
You can do a isLoggedIn(); and verify the age during the member registration process.

```
$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()
```

If it's a Guest and we're just putting in a DOB check via a Form, and then doing a pass/fail with a result in a custom form loaded by your custom template file (.phtml) in your theme.

Either approach can be done with a "Modal" window with Javascript via Jquery (and no conflict) or with Prototype/Scriptaculous.

**prototype:** http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html

**jquery:** http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/build-a-popup-modal-window-using-the-jquery-reveal-plugin/

**jquery tutorial:** http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Hope that helps you go in the right direction, it will take some programming know-how either way.